# How to create a Custom Validator in Python Clint Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, command-line-interface, clint

I am using the Python package named `Clint` to prettify the inputs necessary in my application. In the package you can access the module `validators` and use it combined with `prompt` to properly ask users to input data.

I was looking for a possibility to implement a custom validator in Clint, due to a relatively short list of built-in classes of validators in the module:

```
[FileValidator, IntegerValidator, OptionValidator, PathValidator, RegexValidator, ValidationError]
```

So I wrote the code bellow:

```
from clint.textui import prompt, validators

class NumberValidator(object):
    message = 'Input is not valid.'

    def __init__(self, message=None):
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, value):
        """
        Validates the input.
        """
        try:
            if int(value) > 10:
                return value
            else:
                raise ValueError() 
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise validators.ValidationError(self.message)

answer = prompt.query(f'Insert range in days:',
                      '365',
                      validators=[NumberValidator("Must to be > 10")],
                      batch=False)
print(answer)
```

It works, but I found the solution a bit messy. That is because using this solution I have to create a new class every time I need to perform a new different type of validation.

I think it would be better if somehow the class could be dynamic using `decorators`, accepting a new function each time it would be initiated. But I found myself really bad in the decorators' subject.

So I ask you to help me to make a more Pythonic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I may found a way better to this issue. In the code bellow I can create as much custom functions as I want (`custom_validation_1`, `custom_validation_2`, `custom_validation_3`...) and then just change the parameter `validators` in the `prompt.query`

```
from clint.textui import prompt, validators


class InputValidator(object):
    message = 'Input is not valid.'

    def __init__(self, fun, message=None, *args):
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message
        self.my_function = fun
        self.my_args = args

    def __call__(self, value):
        """
        Validates the input.
        """
        try:
            return self.my_function(value, *self.my_args)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise validators.ValidationError(self.message)


def custom_validation_1(value, number):
    if int(value) > int(number):
        return value
    else:
        raise ValueError


answer = prompt.query(f'Insert range in days:',
                      '365',
                      validators=[InputValidator(custom_validation_1,
                                                 "Must to be greater than 10",
                                                 10)],
                      batch=False)
print(answer)
```